# Generate JPA query for foreign key field

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to get a list of students using teacher id, which is a foreign key in the `Student` table generate using `@JoinColumn` but having errors.

`Student.java` class field relationship:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) 
@JoinColumn(name = "teacher_id", nullable=false)
private Student student;
```

`Teacher.java` class field relationship:

```
@OneToMany(
        mappedBy = "student",
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        orphanRemoval = true
)
private List<Student> StudentsList = new ArrayList<>();
```

`StudentResource.java`:

```
@GetMapping("/student/details/{teacherId}")
@Timed
public List<Student> getStudentDetails(@PathVariable Long teacherId) {
    log.debug("REST request to get Student details: {}", teacherId);
    List<Student> studentDetails= studentRepository.findByTeacherID(teacherId);
    return studentDetails;
}
```

`StudentRepository.java`:

```
List<Student> findByTeacherID(Long teacherId);
```

Is there a way I can map the field directly instead of the whole object?

Comment: Please provide complete code when asking questions. Provide both your entities and the error you are getting...Is there a way I can map the field directly instead of the whole object..?? What do you mean?

Comment: Share your complete Entities

Comment: The `Student` has a `student` attribute of type `student` which is supposed to map to a teacher? Something is wrong with the code you posted.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way I can map the field directly instead of the whole object?

Assuming the code of `Student` looks as one would expect<sup>*</sup> and not as you posted it this should work:

```
@Query("select s.id from Student s where s.teacher.id = :id") 
List<Long> findByTeacherId(Long id);
```

<sup>*</sup> i.e. `Student` has an attribute `teacher` referencing the `Teacher` and an id attribute named `id` of type `Long`.